# Keep my vector from being deleted when the function who called it ends

Tags: c++, scope

My class has a variable
`map<string, vector<int> > base_`

I have a function who creates a vector of zeroes, then indexes the vector into the base_[string c] and make some changes to base_[c], but i can't access any value of base_[c] outside of this function scope, even if using functions from the class.
I believe the vector< int> is being deleted whenever the function ends. How can i keep the vector< int> from being deleted when my function is over?

```
void Index::AddFile(string c, int n, int j){
    vector<int> vi(n, 0);
    vector<string> vc = Conv(c);
    Form(vc);
    cout<<"j e "<<j<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<vc.size();i++){
        if(base_.count(vc[i])==0){
            for (int k=0; k<n; k++){
                this->base_[vc[i]].push_back(vi[i]);
            }
            this->base_[vc[i]][j] = 1;
        } else {
            this->base_[vc[i]][j]++;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: "*I believe the vector< int> is being deleted whenever the function ends.*" What makes you believe that? Can you produce a full [MCVE] that we can run to reproduce what you are seeing that makes you think this?

Comment: @scohe001 it's a local variable in the function. *Of course* it's being destroyed when it goes out of scope / the function ends.

Comment: @Jesper perhaps we're reading the question differently. My understanding is that they're saying the `vector<int>` they're storing in `base_`, the member variable, is deleted when the function is over.

Comment: *but i can't access any value of base_[c] outside of this function* -- I don't understand.  You can see that `base_` is not local, and you already assigned values to it.  You used the `vector<int>` to set the values in `base_`, but once that's done, its done.  You no longer need that `vector<int>` anymore.  So you need to post a [mcve], because something is just not making sense.

Comment: `this->base_[vc[i]].push_back(vi[i]);` -- You do know that you are writing over any map entry with key `vc[i]`, right?  So any data at key `vc[i]` will be "deleted" and replaced.  So is this what you mean by "the vector is being deleted"?

Comment: @Paul if there's already a key with value `vc[i]` (which they confirm there's not with `if(base_.count(vc[i])==0)`, but assuming there was), shouldn't that access the vector there and then push_back to it? Why do you say that will replace the value for that key?

Comment: @scohe001 I was focused on the `vector<int> vi(n, 0);`..

Comment: @scohe001 -- Yes, you're right.  In any case, that `vector<int>` is no longer needed outside of that function, so the OP still needs to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep your vector around, make it a class member instead of a local function variable. Variables are destroyed when they go out of scope.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, i need do create a new vector every time this function is called.

Comment: @atilappl if you need a new one on each function invocation, then why is it a problem that the old one is destroyed? If you just need to keep it around until this function is called again, then still make it a member and just reset it in this function. Please elaborate on what *exactly* you are trying to achieve.